# Is there a trim trailing spaces option in ZeroBrane Studio?

Tags: trim, spaces, trailing, zerobrane

I want the IDE to trim my trailing spaces in my code like I have Notepad++ set to do. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; there is a plugin that enables that: https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage/blob/master/striptrailingwhitespace.lua.